# How to Assemble .il file to .dll

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, manifest, ildasm

I have Disassembled a WPF (Prism).dll file (Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExxtensions.dll) using ILDASM, there I got  3 files with extensions like .IL, .res and .g.resources. I have changed the version number of a referenced file in metadata of the .IL file. Now I need to again Assemble it into a .dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ilasm tool.
I have heard about this workaround too. Make a new application. Add all the resource files then select all files and change the build action to embedded resources for all files.